# Get Polyline with the Here Tour Planning API

Tags: here-api

We're using the Tour Planning API because it seems to be the only routing API that supports time windows, however according to the documentation the Tour Planning API does not return the route polyline.
Is there another way to get the route polyline along with the ordered stops?

Comment: Hi Tom, not sure if you've tried the routing V8. It returns the polyline.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/index.html
You might want to combine tour planning and routing v8.

Comment: So you're saying: find the sequence of the stops using Tour Planning API and then run that stop sequence through the Routing API to get the polyline. How would this work when using time windows and breaks during tour planning? Is there a guarantee the route returned by the Routing API between any two stops matches the route considered (but for some reason, not returned) by the Tour Planning API?

Answer (score 0):

Here Tour Planning and HERE routing are based on the same data; therefore, the tours returned are realistic. In the tour results, the sequence of stops also includes breaks if there are. While requesting the routes from routing API, use all the stops as waypoints (via) with duration at that stop (stopDuration). The resulting route should closely match the tour plan. Depending on the current traffic situation or other factors, there can be a minor difference.
Learn more about waypoint routing here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/waypoint.html

An example of routing request with waypoints and stopDuration looks like this: https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?routingMode=fast&transportMode=car&return=polyline,summary&departureTime=2022-08-01T08:00:00&origin=52.530914,13.384966;radius=100&via=52.525331,13.369311;radius=100!stopDuration=360&via=52.503011,13.341190;radius=100!stopDuration=1200&destination=52.530914,13.384966;radius=100